# How to use centroids of clustering as centroids for next clustering in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I do have the following problem:
I want to do cluster analysis with k-means of two data sets. At first I want to cluster dataset 1 (a) and afterwards I want to cluster dataset 2 (b)  starting from the same centroids found in one.

my data is stored in variables a and b.

First clustering is

```
cluster = kmeans(a,2)
```

second clustering is

```
cluster2 = kmeans(b, cluster[2][1])
```

but I always get an error: "(list) object cannot be tranformed to 'double'.

When I give it an array, let's say:

```
centroids = <- array(dim=c(4,2))
centroids[1,1] <-6.270294
centroids[2,1] <-20.270000
centroids[1,2] <-4.5517412
centroids[2,2] <-21.7670000
```

and cluster it afterwards with

```
cluster2 = kmeans(b, centroids)
```

it works without problems. But I do have another dataset with text and so copying of all the data is not an option.

Does anyone know how to transform this list or another way to make it work? thanks in advance ;)